# Changing value of character using ascii value in swift

Tags: swift, ascii

I'm trying to change a string by changing each individual character.

Right now what I'm doing is reading through the string one character at a time, trying to convert it to ascii, and adding one to the value. I have the following code.

```
  var phrase = textfield1.text
    var i = 0
    for character in phrase
    {
        var s = String(character).unicodeScalars
        s[s.startIndex].value
        println(s[s.startIndex].value)
       if(i == 0)
        {
            s[s.startIndex].value += 1
        }
        if(i == 1)
        {
            s = s + 2
            i = 0
        }
    }
```

My println prints out the correct values for whatever words I enter, however I then am unable to manipulate it in my if statement. When I try it gives the following error:

```
Could not find member 'value'
```

Is it even possible to do what I'm trying?

Answer (score 8):

The `unicodeScalars` property is readonly, so you cannot modify it directly.

What you can do is to build a new string from the (modified) Unicode scalars:

```
var text = "HELLO  !"
var newText = ""

for uni in text.unicodeScalars {
    var val = uni.value
    if val >= 0x41 && val < 0x5A { // If in the range "A"..."Y", just as an example
        val += 1 // or whatever ...
    }
    newText.append(UnicodeScalar(val))
}

println(newText) // "IFMMP  !"
```

But note that `val` is a Unicode value, not an ASCII code. You might want to add
a check if `val` is in the range of alphanumeric characters or similar before
modifying it.

---

**Update for Swift 3:** (Thanks to @adrian.)

```
let text = "HELLO  !"
var newText = ""

for uni in text.unicodeScalars {
    var val = uni.value
    if val >= 0x41 && val < 0x5A { // If in the range "A"..."Y", just as an example
        val += 1 // or whatever ...
    }
    newText.append(Character(UnicodeScalar(val)!))
}

print(newText) // "IFMMP  !"
```

Comment: It looks like the method for specifying the UnicodeScalar value of a new character has changed. I found this, but I can't figure out what I'm supposed to do. https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/String.swift

Comment: @Adrian: I'll update it when I am back at my computer.

Comment: Awesome! I'm making some headway...if I get there before you, I'll post a comment. I'm trying to map them all out with `var stringMap = string.unicodeScalars.map({$0.value})` and run the elements through a switch to increment them.

Comment: `let newChar = UnicodeScalar(value);
 newString.append(Character(newChar!))
` got me over the finish line.

Answer (score 7):

You're getting that error because the `value` property of a `UnicodeScalar` is read-only, but you're attempting to increment it.

Note that changing things in your loop won't have any effect on `phrase` - here's a way to do what you're doing using `map()`:

```
let advanced = String(map(phrase) {
    (ch: Character) -> Character in
    switch ch {
    case " "..."}":                                  // only work with printable low-ASCII
        let scalars = String(ch).unicodeScalars      // unicode scalar(s) of the character
        let val = scalars[scalars.startIndex].value  // value of the unicode scalar
        return Character(UnicodeScalar(val + 1))     // return an incremented character
    default:
        return ch     // non-printable or non-ASCII
    }
})
```

Comment: Probably not an issue here, but this will truncate "extended grapheme clusters" such as flags "".

Comment: You could fix it by adding a check `if ch < "A" || ch > "Y" { return ch }` or whatever is appropriate for the task. (Incrementing *all Unicode characters* does probably make no sense.)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up coming with a pretty simple solution.

I just stored the number in a new variable once I had it converted

```
s = String(character).unicodeScalars
x = s[s.startIndex].value

x += 1
```

Comment: But that does not modify the string. Did we misunderstand your question?

Comment: It doesn't modify the string directly, but it allows me to change an individual character.

It's possible I didn't explain the question clearly.