# Swift Character + Int operation

Tags: ios, swift

I'm rewriting a library from java which uses something like

```
public int myFunc(char c){
 return c+200
}
```

because in java 'a' + 1 will be 'b'

in Swift I cannot simply add an Int to a Character. Google search doesn't know anything about that.

Comment: Go via UnicodeScalar E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259425/how-to-convert-an-int-to-a-character-in-swift

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761390/changing-value-of-character-using-ascii-value-in-swift

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29835826/2303865

Answer (score 0):

Swift is a Strong Type Language. So the typecast is strict.

If you get ASCII value, you can like this:

```
let asciiValues = string.utf8.map{ Int($0) }
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: UTF-8 is not ASCII.

Comment: The ASCII value of English character is equal with the code value of UTF16 and UTF8. So by using this specificity, you can get the ASCII value easily.